# All Caps with Commands

Tags: capitalization

I am trying to set some text in all caps (not small caps) using the `\uppercase` command. Part of the text is variable and stored in a separate command, but that portion of the text is being set in lower case. How do I fix this?

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\test}{lower case}
\uppercase{Why is the last part in \test}?

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using TeX primitives requires knowing what they do. In this case you're trying to use `\uppercase`, but its actions are different from whay you might expect:

1. upon seeing `\uppercase`, TeX looks for `{` (explicit or implicit character token of category code 1) expanding tokens as it goes and ignoring space tokens or `\relax`;
2. once `{` has been found, TeX absorbs tokens ***without expansion*** until it finds a <right brace> (an explicit character token of category code 2);
3. at this point TeX sends the tokens it found down to a different processor that converts *character tokens* to their uppercase version, according to the `\uccode` array (without changing category codes); noncharacter tokens aren't touched;
4. at the end, the resulting token list is sent back in the main input stream to be processed as if it had been there to begin with.

Point 3 applies to your `\test`: what you get is

```
WHY IS THE LAST PART IN \test
```

and when `\test` is found it's expanded to `lower case`.

You might use the “expansion“ feature described in point 1 and do

```
\uppercase\expandafter{\expanded{Why is the last part in \test}}
```

because the expansion of `\expandafter` would trigger `\expanded` that in turn would pass `\uppercase` the token list

```
Why is the last part in lower case
```

But you're better not trying it, unless your text is completely free of accents and several other *dangerous* tokens. The input

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\naive}{na\"ive}

\begin{document}

\uppercase\expandafter{\expanded{This is \naive}}

\end{document}
```

would stop processing with

```
\protect
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
                }
l.7 ...case\expandafter{\expanded{This is \naive}}
```

To the contrary,

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\naive}{na\"ive}

\begin{document}

\MakeUppercase{This is \naive}

\end{document}
```

would work flawlessly.

Another example showing why `\MakeUppercase` is to be used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}

\begin{document}

\MakeUppercase{Bu türkçe bir cümle}% This is a sentence in Turkish

\end{document}
```

produces the correct glyph when uppercasing “i”, according to Turkish orthography:

[image]

Answer (score 19):

Use `\MakeUppercase`

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\test}{lower case}
\newcommand{\testi}{upper case}
\uppercase{Why is the last part in \test}?

\MakeUppercase{Now everything is in \testi}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you are willing and able to use `LuaLaTeX`, you can use Lua's `string.upper` function to perform the conversion to all-uppercase.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\test}{lower case}
\newcommand\LuaUppercase[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint(string.upper("#1"))}}

\usepackage{textgreek}
\begin{document}
\uppercase{Why is the last part in \test}?

\LuaUppercase{Why is the last part in \test}?
\end{document}
```